# Azure Emulator loading incorrect libraries

Tags: azure, version, emulation, nuget

The situation is as follows:

Let's say I have a **project with 2 nuget library references** - lib A and B:

- A is at version 1.5
- but B references an older version of A, e.g. 1.4

In VS, everything can compile and run properly (I guess because A 1.5 implements all the functionality that 1.4 required).

But running in the Azure emulator resulted in an immediate TypeLoadException, presumably because the older version of A was loaded (I think its because B was loaded first, and its dependency was A 1.4), thus the types and methods (e.g. MyObject) added in A 1.5 and used by my project are not recognized.

Exactly what I get is:
"Could not load type 'MyObject' from assembly 'A, Version=1.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'."
I've substituted the real names and version numbers with A and 1.4 of course :)

I know that one solution would be to update B to use A 1.5, but is there any other way to fix this? In case there are other libs B, C, D, E... that use A 1.4, I would have update the reference to A in all of them...

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Either upgrade your projects to use the latest NuGet package or try adding a [binding redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19.aspx) to your app.config to map assembly references to the higher version.

Comment: Hey Matt. Thanks for the suggestion. I have taken a look into it and it looks like the new VS will offer "Automatic binding redirection" which should solve the problem by "always loading the newest version of dll". However, I found something that helps: going to "packages" folder of the solution and removing all dlls that are part of other nuget packages AND are referenced by the project (this would prevent any lingering old versions of the dlls)